# Blazor Server Background Task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm new to Blazor and working on my first project and I have run into a problem and could use some help. Basically to keep it simple lets say I have a webpage and I want to display live data such as a stock tickers price on the page for anyone viewing the page. The webserver should make a single connection to an exchange websocket and read the data stream to get the ticker price. My question is how do I start some kind of background task when the webserver starts to make the connection and keep it alive and so it's only one connection.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an  [`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) for this.